# How to display size attribute selection on Magento simple product front end

Tags: magento

I created configurable products on Magento with attributes colour and size for the main category. I also have a sub category for simple products to display individually, however, i would like the user to be able to select size on simple products as well. How can i enable Magento to display size attribute on simple products? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have this directly.

Example : You have a configurable product named T-Shirt.
You have some simple products named 
Red T-Shirt L
Red T-Shirt XL
Blue T-Shirt M
Blue T-Shirt L
Blue T-Shirt  XXL
Green T-Shirt L

Each simple product correspond to a particular combination of Size and Colour, so it's pointless to be able to change size on the simple product. To fit your needs there are several possibilities :

-1°) Review the $_product->getProductUrl() function to force people going to the configurable, on the subcategory they can see each simple combinations, but if they clic they are redirected to the configurable, pre-configured to the simple clicked, but they are able to change size and colour.

-2°) If you just want to change size once colour selected, just create intermediate configurable product like Blue T-Shirt where use can just select size. Then you redirect to this configurable product. To sum up you have the "main" configurable where you can choose color and size, but if you look at subcategory and already like a color, you have an "intermediate" configurable where you can just choose the size.

-3°) There are other possibility, but less good for this task, but I may name them : using Custom Option of size in each simple, using upsell product to have other size information in the product page and do some scripting (js and html) to show them as a dropdown size selector, ...

Hope this helps